# Redirecting a exception from SQL TASK SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am running a oracle stored proc in my SSIS as 'OLE DB COMMAND'. The input for this stored proc is from 'OLE DB SOURCE' (the input is a id from SQL server table). Now that in my oracle stored proc when ever i get 'No data found' exception I would like to redirect the input id and log the exception into SQL server table. Can you please advise how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: its a stored proc, the logic is that it checks if the id exists in oracle table if it doen't no data exception will raise and I am planning to grab this exception and write into SQL server exception table.

Answer (score 0):

'No data found' probably means the proc failed on Oracle, so you cant redirect it. You could redirect if it were a row level error.

To track the ID that generated the failure, assuming it is stored in a variable, I would drag a red arrow from the data flow component to a Execute Script task and on this task run something like insert into myLogTable values... and pass the ID variable